# Yii2: переопределить ссылку для незалогиненых пользователей

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

Если пользователю запрещен доступ на страницу, его перекидывает на страницу /login. Как изменить эту ссылку? мне надо что бы перекидывало на /

Answer (score 0):

При использовании фильтра ACF в контроллере, можно переопределить свойство `denyCallback`, которое принимает функцию. А там уже в этой функции осуществить необходимое перенаправление.

```
[
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
        $this->redirect();
    }
]
```

[Подробнее про ACF фильтр](https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-security-authorization.html)